# How to replace the entire layout with a webview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Edittext, a button and a ListView in my activity. Now when any of the options on listview are selected i want to replace everything by a webview and if the user presses back i want to come back to the original view.
How do i do this?
I looked at View flipper but that is mostly used if you switch between views a lot, also is it a good idea to use webview with viewflipper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the visiblity of the views, so setup a webview that fills the screen then set its visibility to gone in your xml, then when you want to display it use `myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in your code to display the webview, it would probable be a good idead to make your buttons etc invisible using `myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

It would however be easier just to setup another activity with your webview in and just start that activity when required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, Is these any reference you can give me on how to define and start another activity from my existing one.

Comment: have a look at this video tutorial, it covers setting up another activity, it goes over the java code, xml and changes to the manifest that you need to do. link: http://youtu.be/sWOXbDYwIXo

Answer (score 0):

In view method of item Listener of your code do something like this...

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("Web link here"));

and you are done with it...

Or please post your code so I can help you in better manner...

Comment: I don't need an intent, this will open up a browser, I need a webview.